# Select Exists always return true in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, select, promise

I am trying to make a login form where I have to register user before that. But this code always says that user already exists even if it's not the case. What am I doing wrong?

```
connection.query("select exists (select * from demoApp where username = '" + username + " ')", function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
        LOG.error(error);
        return;
    }
    else {
        LOG.info(result);
        if (result) {
            LOG.info("Username already exists!");
        }

        else {

            connection.query("INSERT INTO demoApp (username, password) VALUES( '" + username + "', '" + password + "')", function (error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    LOG.error(error);

                    return;
                }
                else {
                    LOG.info("Username added.");

                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

};

Comment: what is logged by `LOG.info(result);` ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya {"ts":"2019:10:15:08:32:11","level":"info","message":[{"exists (select * from demoApp where username = 'lala ')":0}]}    This is printed if it doesn't exist .... otheriwse .... {"ts":"2019:10:15:08:32:11","level":"info","message":[{"exists (select * from demoApp where username = 'lala ')":1}]} ... this is printed.

Comment: What value you are getting in result variable? Looks like you are not getting 0 or 1 in result variable

Comment: You're taking the username the user supplied and concatenating it into an SQL. This I dangerous; absolutely do not do this. Read http://Bobby-Tables.com

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya {"ts":"2019:10:15:08:32:11","level":"info","message":[{"exists (select * from demoApp where username = 'lala ')":0}]} This is what I am getting.. 0 and 1 change depending if the user exists or not

Comment: Also like to point out that your query for searching a user concatenates a space onto the end of what the user provided but the query that inserts a username does not. This cannot work properly

Comment: `Select exists` will always return 1 or 0, 1 to be true and 0 to be false, in your case your only checking if there is a result returned, which will always be true if not errored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say in the title of the question "MySQL always returns true..." is incorrect; you later say in the comments that MySQL is returning 0 or 1

Your JavaScript has a flaw in the logic. You're saying `if(result)` but result is far more than just a simple Integer 0 or 1 so saying if(result) will effectively be testing if it's null or not, which is never is, hence "always true"

Your code should look more like this (I also fixed the problem that your old code is open to injection hacking:

```
//alias the result column using AS xxx to make it easier to refer to in js
//ALWAYS use parameters (WHERE username = ?) to pass values from the user into the db
let sql = "select exists (select * from demoApp where username = ?) as userExists";
connection.query(sql, [username],
function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
        LOG.error(error);
        return;
    }
    else {
        LOG.info(result);
        if (result[0].userExists == 1) { //no harm in being explicit. Result is a collection of rows with names of columns, index it to get the first and specify the column (which is really hard to do with name of you don't alias your query result
            LOG.info("Username already exists!");
        }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

seems your `exists` operator is returning results `0 and 1`. check on how to use this [operator](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-exists/)

```
connection.query("select exists (select * from demoApp where username = '" + username + " ')", function (error, result) {
```

this should be enough

```
connection.query("select 1 from demoApp where username = '" + username + " '", function (error, result) {
```

then check the affected rows.

```
if (result.affectedRows > 0) {
    LOG.info("Username already exists!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this > SELECT * from demoApp WHERE EXISTS(SELECT username FROM demoApp  WHERE username = '" + username + "')